# Show "Most Recent" on Facebook Touch?

Tags: facebook, mobile, android

Wondering if anyone knows how to make the [touch.facebook](http://touch.facebook.com) home page show the most recent items in your news feed. It seems to just show whatever random posts it feels like showing, from minutes ago, or even from 20-30 hours ago! I'd prefer to see the most recent items as they come through, a la "Live Feed" style. It seems to work that way on the [m.facebook](http://m.facebook.com) domain. The touch domain has a much nicer interface, but the data on m is much more up-to-date. In that regard the touch one is almost useless!

Running on an Android Galaxy S fwiw; (The Facebook app seems to suffer from the same out-of-date problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AHA. Just figured this one out - I was having the same problem.

It seems that if you hit the tab named 'News Feed', it will toggle between showing either the News Feed OR the Live Feed. If you enable Live Feed, you'll get the latest updates.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: WOOHOO!!! Thank you for that!!! It was driving me ***CrAzY*** only getting what FB thought was "the most relevant" postings, or whatever they call it. **THANK YOU!** :)